# Предыдущий и следующий строки в таблице БД

Tags: php, sql, mysql

В SQL-запросах не силен, поэтому помогите, пожалуйста.

Скрипту передается id-строки в таблице БД. Строки таблиц содержать поле user_id - идентификатор пользователя.

Нужно написать запрос, чтобы он выбрал ID предыдущей и следующей строки относительно id-строки, посылаемом в скрипт, из всех строк пользователя, привязанного к текущей строки (то есть строки, id которой передается скрипту).

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял постановку вопроса, то вот так:

```
SELECT
 MAX(t2.`id`) as prev_id,
 MIN(t3.`id`) as next_id
FROM `table` t1
LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t2.`user_id` = t1.`user_id` AND t2.`id` > t1.`id`
LEFT JOIN `table` t3 ON t3.`user_id` = t1.`user_id` AND t3.`id` < t1.`id`
WHERE t1.`id` = {$id}
```

Comment: Это мой вариант, пока что рабочий.

    SELECT
        (SELECT id FROM `tovar` WHERE id < $id AND user_id=t.user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS prev_id,
        (SELECT id FROM `tovar` WHERE id > $id AND user_id=t.user_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,1) AS next_id
        FROM `tovar` t
        WHERE id=$id

Ваш вариант не работает. Но хотелось именно такой вариант с джойнами. Выводит первый попавшийся id больше/меньше текущей строки.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант

```
SELECT id
FROM `table`
WHERE id = (select id from `table` where id > 3 order by id ASC limit 1) 
OR (id = (select id from `table` where id < 3 order by id DESC limit 1))
```

результат: вывод 2х строк с id=2 и id=4

А вот группировка. Т.е. есть две таблицы, например, db_users и enter_obj. Во второй таблице типа юзерские данные, например, контактные имя и телефон. Чтобы вывести id + имя + телефон из разных таблиц, получился такой запрос:

```
SELECT
  db_users.id, enter_obj.enConName, enter_obj.enConTel
FROM
  db_users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN enter_obj ON db_users.id = enter_obj.id
WHERE
  db_users.id = (SELECT db_users.id FROM db_users WHERE db_users.id > 3 ORDER BY db_users.id LIMIT 1)
OR db_users.id = (SELECT db_users.id FROM db_users WHERE db_users.id < 3 ORDER BY db_users.id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

на выходе получаем следующее:

```
id | enConName | enConTel
2 | Василий | +79261112233
4 | Илюша | +79265556677
```

Comment: А сгруппировать по пользователю?

Comment: >а надо бы одной строкой, чтобы я не прогонял по цыклу

тогда я что-то не понял тебя

Comment: Мне просто нужны идентификаторы строк, чтобы вывести ссылки "Предыдущая Следующая" на записи пользователя, который указан в текущей записи. Причем результат должен выдать одну "запись" содержащую два идентификатора.

В любом случае вопрос решен уже.

Comment: и если не секрет, то какое решение?

Comment: В комментарии к ответу от @sambady рабочая версия, которая удовлетворяет моим требованиям.

Answer (score 0):

А не проще это реализовать в самом коде? Примерно так:

```
$userid = x;
$prevuserid = x-1; 
$nextuserid = x+1;
```

Comment: Не проще, ибо следующей записю данного пользователья может быть под ID=12333, в то время как настоящий ID=25